# Are Office Web Apps 2013 patches cumulative?

Tags: 2013, office-web-apps, patching

I have an Office Web Apps 2013 farm, unpatched since installation. It was initially installed with SP1 and there are 30 patches released since then. 
So I'm wondering if I have to apply every patch one by one or I can install only the last one, just as we do for SharePoint CU nowadays.
Can anyone share some info on this, references or own experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they're cumulative. Generally they're presented as security patches, but those patches are the 'CU'. Don't forget the patching process for WAC:

1. Remove the WAC server from the WAC farm
2. Install patch/reboot
3. Create a new WAC farm

Repeat steps 1 and 2 for the other WAC servers, but join them to the new farm you created with the first WAC machine to be updated.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor. That's good to hear...
Microsoft has a nice guide on the process of patching WAC farm: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj966220.aspx